# Email addresses in Mail.app displayed as string of numbers!

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

I'm on a MBP running Sonoma 14.1.1
Using Mail.app with Gmail IMAP.

In Mail.app, when viewing an email, the To: email addresses are showing up with a string of numbers.

For example instead of:
me (at) gmail.com
I see:
<1502D7E4-E347-40C2-911A-FDB643323449DCAF (at) gmail.com>

This only appears when viewing emails. When I compose an email and enter an email address, it fills in normally.
I do NOT see this behaviors when using Gmail in a browser.
I've reviewed my settings in Mail.app and Gmail, but do not see anything that could be causing this.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: When you reply to such a mail, does the adress in the reply still show numbers or does it change to the usual adress?

Comment: @nohillside - If I reply, the address in the reply is formatted normally. (sorry for delay in replying...)